# Is this a finite integral?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

A book on probability theory I am reading asserts the following: for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, t \geq 0$, consider the function $h_t(x, y) = \frac{1}{t^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{4t}}$, where $r = |x - y|$. Then the following integral is finite:
$$ 
H(x, y) = \int_0^{r^2} h_t(x, y)dt.$$

It is not clear to me how they are calculating it. Furthermore, it seems from the discussion (I am not completely sure here) that the final answer is something like (constant)$r^{\frac{n - 2}{2}}$. I would really appreciate a little help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u=\frac{1}{t}$, then (assuming $r>0$)
$$ \int_0^{r^2}t^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\frac{r^2}{4t}}\;dt=\int_{r^{-2}}^{\infty}u^{\frac{n}{2}-2}e^{-\frac{r^2u}{4}}\;du $$
which is finite because of the exponential decay at infinity. Then setting $v=\frac{r^2}{4}u$, we have
$$ \int_{r^{-2}}^{\infty}u^{\frac{n}{2}-2}e^{-\frac{r^2u}{4}}\;du=\frac{4^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{r^{n-2}}\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\infty}v^{\frac{n}{2}-2}e^{-v}\;dv=\frac{4^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{r^{n-2}}\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}-1,\frac{1}{4}\Big)$$
where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the (upper) incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: You mean $\frac{1}{r^{n - 2}}$, right?

Comment: Yes, good point.